# How to get a state that the outgoing call has been answered?

Tags: java, android, phone-call

I'm using `PhoneStateListener`'s `onCallStateChanged` method to track the states of an outgoing phone call. I need to get the state of the outgoing call when accepted. I was using `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` to determine the answering state, but it is called even when the call receiver ignores the incoming call. Is there any accurate and possible way to get the phone call answered state?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  I've seen the question asked a lot but no answers.

Comment: Wow, congrats!  Any clues for the rest of us trying to do the same thing?

Comment: @brianestey: instead of detecting the outgoing call connection state, it is easy to get the duration of the last dialed call.

Comment: Ahh, interesting approach.  I'll give that a try.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @brianestey:welcome, brian :)

Comment: Wrong. Duration is set even if the phone is never picked up. You can verify that by calling a number that doesn't get answered and either hang up or let the phone call expire. The Call log will show a duration.