# Android Phone Calling states

Tags: android, android-intent

For calling there are two main possible cases

- 1st case: User B calling user me (suppose I am the user A)
- 2nd case: User A (I am) calling to user B

In 1st case
There will be three states of calls
`CALL_STATE_IDLE`, `CALL_STATE_RINGING` and `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`

User B calling to user A (myphone).

When user B calling me (A) , phone state  1st it will go in ringing state and when I answer the call it will go in off-hook state and when I am or user B end the call control will go in idle state that is fine .

Using 1st case of calling we can detect three states of phone on user A side.

2nd case : In 2nd case when I am calling to user B.

Control going inside `IDLE` state then off hook state without answer,

Anyone can describe how I can identify User B attend (answer) my call on my side (on user A side) ?

Comment: There isn't any supported API for that, but you could try what I suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039098/android-detecting-when-lines-have-been-connected-during-an-outgoing-call

Comment: Hi @Michael I try that method it saying class not found "com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager" because this is core class ,application developer have no access to use this class . .