# How can I detect outgoing call is connected in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

how I can detect when outgoing call is connected. My code is below but when have incomingcall it get in this **if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))**

when there is not activity it get in this

**else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))**

when incomingcall is answer it will get in this and outgoingcall it will get in this.

**else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))**

and now when outgoingcall it's state is offhook how can i know when my outgoingcall is connected.

Thank you

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Call From : " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
        Toast.makeText(context,TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
        Toast.makeText(context,TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039098/android-detecting-when-lines-have-been-connected-during-an-outgoing-call please check below link.

Answer (score -1):

Add this in Android Manifest file. Declare Broadcast receiver.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".OutCallLogger"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PRECISE_CALL_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Add below permissions in android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Also add this line in manifest file.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony">
</uses-feature>
```

And this is your class which will be used for getting precised call state for outgoing calls.

```
public class OutCallLogger extends BroadcastReceiver {
public OutCallLogger() {
}
TelephonyManager Tm;
ITelephony telephonyService;
Class c = null;
Method methodGetInstance = null;
Method methodGetActiveFgCallState=null;
String TAG="Tag";
Object objectCallManager=null;
Context context1;
Class<?> classCallManager;

Class telephonyClass;
Class telephonyStubClass;
Class serviceManagerClass;
Class serviceManagerStubClass;
Class serviceManagerNativeClass;
Class serviceManagerNativeStubClass;

Method telephonyCall;
Method telephonyEndCall;
Method telephonyAnswerCall;
Method getDefault;

Method[] temps;
Constructor[] serviceManagerConstructor;

// Method getService;
Object telephonyObject;
Object serviceManagerObject;
private Timer timer= null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.



    this.context1= context;
    try {
        //String serviceManagerName = "android.os.IServiceManager";
        String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
        String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
        String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";


        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
        telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
        serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
        serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);

        Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
                serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);

        Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod(
                "asInterface", IBinder.class);

        Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
        tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");

        serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
        IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
        Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
        Method[] aClassMethods = telephonyClass.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method m : aClassMethods)
        {
            //Log.e("MEthods", m.getName());
        }
        telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
        //telephonyCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("call", String.class);
        telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("getPreciseCallState");
        //telephonyAnswerCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("answerRingingCall");
        Log.e("CallState",telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject).toString());
        Toast.makeText(context1, " "+telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Toast will appear which will tell you precise call state. You can modify your code accordingly. Above code which you posted can only be used in case of incoming calls.

Comment: Thank you. i've tried your code already but i get nothing. have no toast when client answer. I don't know what i did wrong. @Hammad Tariq Sahi

Comment: do you get toast when outgoing call is initiated ?

Comment: Sorry. Where should i get toast now i'm so confused @Hammad Tariq Sahi